# Redirect to URL without trailing slash doesn't work in Websphere 8.5.5

Tags: java, redirect, websphere, contextpath

In the application I work with, I have the problem described in the bug PI22830 (websphere :  [PI22830: 404 NOT FOUND ERROR GENERATED FOR A REQUEST WITHOUT A TRAILING SLASH](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI22830) ).

For example:
`http://hostname/myApp` - fails with 404 error  
`http://hostname/myApp/` - success

I have the fix pack 12 installed, which contains the solution to the bug (according to the documentation) 
I added the "prependSlashToResource" property, without solving the problem ([Web container custom properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html#field7_rweb_custom_props))

Has anyone had this problem and was able to solve it? 
Any recommendations to try or investigate?

From already thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

According to IBM documentation you can set custom properties in the administrative console click Servers > Server Types > WebSphere application servers > server_name > Web Container Settings > Web container.
From Additional Properties, select Custom Properties and add new with name `com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.redirectcontextroot` and value `true`.